# Make a float only show two decimal places

Tags: objective-c, formatting, floating-point

I have the value `25.00` in a `float`, but when I print it on screen it is `25.0000000`.
How can I display the value with only two decimal places?

Comment: var nf = NSNumberFormatter()
        nf.positiveFormat = "0.##"
        var numberAfterRound = nf.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: number))!

Answer (score 663, accepted):

It is not a matter of how the number is stored, it is a matter of how you are displaying it. When converting it to a string you must round to the desired precision, which in your case is two decimal places.

E.g.:

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
```

`%.02f` tells the formatter that you will be formatting a float (`%f`) and, that should be rounded to two places, and should be padded with `0`s.

E.g.:

```
%f = 25.000000
%.f = 25
%.02f = 25.00
```

Comment: I noticed that using %.2f actually returns 25.00 in your example and not 25. This is strange.

Comment: The way i always understood was that the number after the decimal point said how much decimals you got. So, .2f would indeed give 25.00, and .4f would give 25.0000.

Comment: If anyone is curious _as to how one does_ **actually get** `25`.. `@"%.f"` does the trick.  What is written above, **does not**.

Comment: can the integer which determines the number of decimal places be a variable? like @"%.xf" where x can be any integer?

Comment: @acecapades, if you use `@"%.*f", decimalPlaces, number`

Comment: Probably this will be a partial off-topic but I would add another format: `%03.f = 025`

Comment: %03.f gives me 025, but %03.02f gives me 25.00... there a good way to get 025.00?

Comment: A reference for this would be nice. I couldn't track down this information in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265 or in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html which is surprising given what a simple task this is - I'd expect it to be very clearly documented in a highly visible place. Do you still recall how you first came by this knowledge?

Comment: %.0f will get you no decimal places

Answer (score 202):

Here are few corrections-

```
//for 3145.559706
```

---

**Swift 3**

```
let num: CGFloat = 3145.559706
print(String(format: "%f", num)) = 3145.559706
print(String(format: "%.f", num)) = 3145
print(String(format: "%.1f", num)) = 3145.6
print(String(format: "%.2f", num)) = 3145.56
print(String(format: "%.02f", num)) = 3145.56 // which is equal to @"%.2f"
print(String(format: "%.3f", num)) = 3145.560
print(String(format: "%.03f", num)) = 3145.560 // which is equal to @"%.3f"
```

---

**Obj-C**

```
@"%f"    = 3145.559706
@"%.f"   = 3146
@"%.1f"  = 3145.6
@"%.2f"  = 3145.56
@"%.02f" = 3145.56 // which is equal to @"%.2f"
@"%.3f"  = 3145.560
@"%.03f" = 3145.560 // which is equal to @"%.3f"
```

and so on...

Comment: Is the last one accurate? @"%.03f" = 3145.566? How did you get .566 instead of .560?

Comment: can the integer which determines the number of decimal places be a variable? like @"%.xf" where x can be any integer?

Comment: If you are having issues with @"%.f" then try @"%.0f". I found this worked to get no decimal places where the other one didn't

Comment: Can anyone tell me why you would use %.02f instead of just %.2f?

Answer (score 20):

You can also try using NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
nf.positiveFormat = @"0.##";
NSString* s = [nf stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: myFloat]];
```

You may need to also set the negative format, but I think it's smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: you need this float numTwoDecimalDigits = atof([s UTF8String]);

Answer (score 10):

I made a swift extension based on above answers

```
extension Float {
    func round(decimalPlace:Int)->Float{
        let format = NSString(format: "%%.%if", decimalPlace)
        let string = NSString(format: format, self)
        return Float(atof(string.UTF8String))
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let floatOne:Float = 3.1415926
let floatTwo:Float = 3.1425934
print(floatOne.round(2) == floatTwo.round(2))
// should be true
```

Comment: This solution also seems to work with CGFloat. Awesome!

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 9):

In Swift Language, if you want to show you need to use it in this way. To assign double value in UITextView, for example:

```
let result = 23.954893
resultTextView.text = NSString(format:"%.2f", result)
```

If you want to show in LOG like as objective-c does using NSLog(), then in Swift Language you can do this way:

```
println(NSString(format:"%.2f", result))
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with all the answers is that multiplying and then dividing results in precision issues because you used division.  I learned this long ago from programming on a PDP8.
The way to resolve this is:

```
return roundf(number * 100) * .01;
```

Thus 15.6578 returns just 15.66 and not 15.6578999 or something unintended like that.

What level of precision you want is up to you.  Just don't divide the product, multiply it by the decimal equivalent.
No funny String conversion required.

Answer (score 3):

IN objective-c, if you are dealing with regular char arrays (instead of pointers to NSString) you could also use:

```
printf("%.02f", your_float_var);
```

OTOH, if what you want is to store that value on a char array you could use:

```
sprintf(your_char_ptr, "%.02f", your_float_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

in objective -c is u want to display float value in 2 decimal number then pass argument indicating how many decimal points u want to display
e.g 0.02f will print 25.00
    0.002f will print 25.000

Answer (score 1):

Here's some methods to format dynamically according to a precision:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (string.length) {
        NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        return [f numberFromString:string];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

+ (NSString *)stringByFormattingString:(NSString *)string toPrecision:(NSInteger)precision
{
    NSNumber *numberValue = [self numberFromString:string];

    if (numberValue) {
        NSString *formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%ldf", (long)precision];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, numberValue.floatValue];
    } else {
        /* return original string */
        return string;
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
[TSPAppDelegate stringByFormattingString:@"2.346324" toPrecision:4];
```

=> 2.3453

```
[TSPAppDelegate stringByFormattingString:@"2.346324" toPrecision:0];
```

=> 2

```
[TSPAppDelegate stringByFormattingString:@"2.346324" toPrecision:2];
```

=> 2.35 (round up)

Comment: That's very good solution, big thanks. Can you explain to me how it works? I see you've added extra '%' symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Another method for ***Swift*** (without using NSString):

```
let percentage = 33.3333
let text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.02f %@", percentage, "%")
```

P.S. this solution is not working with *CGFloat* type only tested with `Float` & `Double`

Comment: @Unknown downvoter this is working solution for swift & also different from other answers for swift so why?

Comment: if you can return a float you can always convert it to a CGFloat

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` with `maximumFractionDigits` as below:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.345]]);
```

And you will get `12.35`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to float value as well:

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
float floatTwoDecimalDigits = atof([formattedNumber UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 lblMeter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",[[dic objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue]];
```