# How do I round a NSNumber to zero decimal spaces

Tags: objective-c

How do I round an NSNumber to zero decimal spaces, in the following line it seems to keep the decimal spaces:

```
NSNumber holidayNightCount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sHolidayDuration.value];
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576110/nstimeinterval-to-readable-nsnumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need an integer why not just use an int

```
int holidayNightCount = (int)sHolidayDuration.value;
```

By definition an int has no decimal places

If you need to use NSNumber, you could just cast the Double to Int and then use the int to create your NSNumber.

```
int myInt = (int)sHolidayDuration.value;
NSNumber holidayNightCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];
```

Comment: floor is more likely the desired behavior

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg Technically this should truncate, which is the same as floor.

Comment: Floor and truncation are different for negatives.

Answer (score 14):

Typically casting to int truncates.  For example, 3.4 becomes 3 (as is desired), but 3.9 becomes 3 also.  If this happens, add 0.5 before casting

```
int myInt = (int)(sHolidayDuration.value + 0.5);
```

Comment: That is such a witty way of getting around the round up. I had never thought of doing it that way cause of built in rounding tools in ios. I like this answer a lot way to be thinking.

Comment: This wouldn't really work with negative numbers though

Comment: For negative numbers try this
 `int myInt = (int)(sHolidayDuration.value > 0 ? sHolidayDuration.value + 0.5 : sHolidayDuration.value - 0.5);`

Answer (score 12):

Here's a bit of a long winded approach

```
float test = 1.9;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter  stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:test]]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: This is more what I was looking for.  In my case I wanted a decimal place or two, and in that respect this method is more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do the following: int roundedRating = (int)round(rating.floatValue);

Answer (score 0):

Floor the number using the old C function floor() and then you can create an NSInteger which is more appropriate, see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/floor.3.html ....

```
NSInteger holidayNightCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:floor(sHolidayDuration.value)].integerValue;
```

Further information on the topic here: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/07/19/objective-c-rounding-float-numbers/

Or you could use NSDecimalNumber features for rounding numbers.