# Cocoa how to display float value with one decimal values without round off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a floating point value, but when i need to represent to the user I need it to show to one decimal place, without rounding off. so basically i need to truncate to up to one decimal place.
for example 
 95.56 -> 95.5

Comment: [find answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/how-to-set-the-float-value-to-two-decimal-number-in-objective-c

Comment: @SaqibSaud, all these answer in that page will round off the value, but i dont want to round off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

sudo code

convert number to string.

find "." in string.

make a substring from start to "." position +1

Comment: Even I was thinking that way, but number formatter is better solution, and performance wise is better compare to string manipulation

Answer (score 6):

`NSNumberFormatter` will do this for you.

`-setMaximumFractionDigits:`
`-setRoundingMode:`

**Update**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter new] autorelease];
    [nf setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
    [nf setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
    NSLog(@"The number is '%@'", [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:95.56]]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Yields:

> 2012-02-16 02:39:49.799 NumberFormatter[14592:903] The number is '95.5'

Comment: wat should is set in rounding mode

Comment: 95.56 to 95.5 would use `NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor`

Comment: but with this I am getting 95.6

Comment: are you sure? that would be a bug (unless another trait is interfering)

Comment: (In response to deleted response) At your suggestion, I did try it myself. It worked as I expected. See the update.

Comment: sorry my mistake, it works like a charm, thank you, can u care to explain me the explaination, what is going on in behind

Comment: you're welcome. There are a few rounding modes -- `NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor ` rounds similar to the C math function `floor(double)` *however* the formatter will scale the argument for the fraction digits.

Comment: but this approach has one problem if value is 16.8, then it will give result 16.7

Comment: that's floating point behavior in C languages! - a floating point number is not a string, and it's not exact. if you `printf` a `float` representing `16.8`, you may see `16.799999`. `floor` that memory representation, and you have `16.7`.

Comment: ok, so finally i have to use string conversion logic only then

Answer (score 5):

try out with this example

```
float t = 25.55;
NSLog(@"%.1f", t);
```

it shows 25.5 if you set %.2f you get 25.55

Comment: if here t =25.56, then it shows 25.6, rather i want to show 25.5 only