# how to show only two digits after the decimal in float value in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a float number i want that it should display only two digits after decimal like if its is 1.566666 it simply show 1.56

I am using this way for float in my code

```
    float ProfitForCerenia=costtoclient/markup;

float totalProfit=costtoclient-ProfitForCerenia;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a float only show two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places)

Comment: You probably should not use floats for money. Generally it's a good idea to use integers, as you wont get any rounding errors on addition / subtraction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you want a NSString with your number:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", floatVal];
```

Comment: No my float number now is 1.555555 i want it to be like 1.55 only

Comment: So you want your float changed? floatVal = ((int)(floatVal * 100)) / 100; but that's really ugly...