# Moving a decimal point 2 places to the right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, int

Im dividing 2 double values with this code:

```
  float final = cw / q ;
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", final];
```

this code works perfectly but the how can i move the decimal point two spaces to the right.

Like this:
.500000 to 50.000 or just 50

Thanks

Comment: its very simple, just multiply by 100 :)

Comment: Did you try   `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", final*100];` ?

Comment: are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places

Comment: @GirishKolari he's asking a simple question...and that's not it.

Comment: Off topic: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: voting to close.Very low standard question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erm, how about multiplying by 100 before converting to text?

```
float final =  ( cw / q ) * 100.0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot.