# How do I make a float display only significant figures Objective C

Tags: iphone, format, significant-digits

I have a float number that displays with a certain number of decimal places after it no matter what, even if it is a round number. How do I format it so that it only displays significant figures with no trailing zeros.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places

Comment: @yan you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Yan  Those answers all require you to know the number of digits.  This question asks for significant digits, which could be "1.25" or "5" or "7.32816".

Comment: Can't you use @Yan 's suggestion, after you have checked for non zero figures?