# How to get 1 decimal Float in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I want to extract 1 decimal float number from existing float number.

I have done this in Objective-C:
[Make a float only show two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places)

**Any idea how to make it happen in Swift?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the same in swift :

```
var formatter : NSString = NSString(format: "%.01f", myFloat)
```

Or like you want in one line :

```
println("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = "+(NSString(format: "%.01f", myFloat)))
```

This work too with the old NSLog (but prefer println) :

```
NSLog("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = %.01f \n", myFloat)
```

Comment: thats technically correct, but how can i print this without adding one more line for string. Ex the below code wont compile:

Comment: println("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = \(NSString(format: "%.01f", experience))") // Here experience is float which i want to be 1-decimal place. (This was possible in objective-C)

Comment: This complile for me println("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = "+(NSString(format: "%.01f", experience)))

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var experience = 10.25
println("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = " + NSString(format: "%.01f", experience))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about an infix operator?

```
// Declare this at file level, anywhere in you project. 
// Expressions of the form 
//     "format string" %% doubleValue
// will return a string. If the string is not a well formed format string, you'll
// just get the string back! If you use incorrect format specifiers (e.g. %d for double)
// you'll get 0 as the formatted value.
operator infix %% { }
@infix func %% (format: String, value: Double) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}

// ...
// You can then use it anywhere
let experience = 1.234
println("Pro Forma:- \n Total Experience(In Years) = %.01f" %% experience)
```

I've tried to do it with generics, but I can't see how. To make it work with multiple types, just overload it for those types - e.g.

```
operator infix %% { }
@infix func %% (format: String, value: Double) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
@infix func %% (format: String, value: Float) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
@infix func %% (format: String, value: Int) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

Comment: Interesting! However, it will really help if you can add comments against the code written by you.

Comment: Which part needs commented? I'm trying to make it work using generics at the moment, and will comment it properly when I'm finished!

Comment: I've just started with Swift. Can you explain the @infix directive?

Comment: Do you have The Book? It's free, and pretty much essential. Chapter is called "Operator Functions", or just use iBook search to look for @infix.

Comment: Ya i've the book from Apple, will have a look at that portion. Well, the comments are descriptive enough to catch. Thanks!