# How rounded decimal 2

Tags: ios, objective-c

How rounded decimal 2?

48382,06 + 86106,62 + 83650,07 + 72939,61 = 291078,36

```
NSNumber *returnSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [arraySum count]; i++) {
        PayDoc *payDoc = (PayDoc*)([arraySum objectAtIndex:i]);
        returnSum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[returnSum floatValue]+[payDoc.SOBTR floatValue]];
    }
```

Answer result my code returnSum = 291078,38

Comment: use numberWithInt instead numberWithFloat

Comment: I need 291078,36! Your method 291078,00.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a float only show two decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places)

Comment: what is type of **payDoc.SOBTR**

Comment: from where are you getting values for sum?? from string or else where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSDecimalNumber`. Set `scale` to `2` and `roundingMode` to `NSRoundPlain`

```
NSDecimalNumber *returnSum = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.0f];

for (PayDoc *payDoc in arraySum) {

        NSDecimalNumber *sobtr = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:payDoc.SOBTR.floatValue];
        returnSum = [returnSum decimalNumberByAdding:sobtr withBehavior:[NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:2 raiseOnExactness:YES raiseOnOverflow:YES raiseOnUnderflow:YES raiseOnDivideByZero:YES]];
}
```

I tested the above values and it gives **291078.36**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
returnSum = @(  roundf([returnSum floatValue] * 100) / 100 + roundf([payDoc.SOBTR floatValue] * 100) / 100  );
```

That will cause the float to only **have** two digits (approximately...) after the decimal point, not to just show two digits as the other comments and answers suggest.

Alternatively if you dont want to round the floats and just want to strip off the decimal digits you can write

```
returnSum = @(  (int)([returnSum floatValue] * 100) / 100.0 + (int)([payDoc.SOBTR floatValue] * 100) / 100.0  );
```

Comment: returnSum = @ (roundf ([returnSum floatValue] * 100) / 100 + roundf ([payDoc.SOBTR floatValue] * 100) / 100); 291078,38

Comment: sorry, forgot an `n` in `roundf`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:[returnSum floatValue]+[payDoc.SOBTR floatValue]];`

Comment: I need 291078,36! Your method 291078,00.

Comment: you can use @"%.2f"  = 3145.56 as NSString* number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", floatNumber];

Answer (score -1):

The best to do this is the following:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[returnSum floatValue]+[payDoc.SOBTR floatValue]]];

NSLog(@"Result...%@",numberString);
```