# Formatting float values in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, numbers, number-formatting

I have weight values, they can be like 75kg and 75.5kg.

I want to have this values two styles: 75kg, 75.5kg, but NOT 75.0kg. How can I do it?

I have this solution, but I not like it

```
//show difference in 75 and 75.5 values style
NSString *floatWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",weightAtThePoint.floatValue];
NSString *intWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f.0",weightAtThePoint.floatValue];
NSString *resultWeight;
if ([floatWeight isEqualToString:intWeight]) {
    resultWeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",weightAtThePoint.floatValue];
} else {
    resultWeight = floatWeight;
}
```

Comment: what you want can you explain me

Comment: I want to have this values two styles: 75kg, 75.5kg, but NOT 75.0kg.

Comment: Is there any Formatting number solution for this?

Comment: You can try this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be using a number formatter:

```
 static NSNumberFormatter * numberformatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        numberformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [numberformatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
        [numberformatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
        [numberformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    });
```

Since the number formatter creation requires some resources is better if you create a single instance.
When you need to print a string just call this:

```
NSString * formattedString = [numberformatter stringFromNumber: weightAtThePoint];<br>
```

`NSNumberFomatter` prints only the decimal number if it is different from 0  and it also helps you in choosing the correct decimal separator by using the current locale on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like your solution, then take look at my solution

```
float flotvalue = weightAtThePoint.floatValue;
int reminder = flotvalue / 1.0;
if (reminder==flotvalue) {
    NSLog(@"%f",flotvalue); //75KG Solution
}
else {
    //75.xx solution
}
```

Enjoy Coding