# Double printing same as float

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, double-precision

Why is my double variable storing and printing as a float. Using Xcode.

```
 #import <limits.h>
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 long double doubleTest = .123456789101112;
 float floatTest = .123456789101112;

 NSLog(@"Float %f vs Double %Lf", floatTest, doubleTest);

// Output - Float 0.123457 vs Double 0.123457
```

Comment: You haven't specified how many digits to print in the format statement.

Comment: There are lots of questions about this on StackOverflow. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/560517/558933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

long double doubleTest = .123456789101112;
 float floatTest = .123456789101112;

NSLog(@"Float %.nf vs Double %.nLf", floatTest, doubleTest);

replace "n" in the above line with however many number's you'd like to print after decimal point, for instance if you use 6 it will print 6 digits after decimal.

Hope this helps.