# Possibly to set float digit precision in display string dynamically without NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know how to format a float when displaying it as part of an NSString (see e.g. [Make a float only show two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places)) but is there a way to dynamically set the number of decimal digits to be displayed? For example, if I know I want `int dig` digits can I modify the following expression to format my float as desired?

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
```

I know I can do this with `NSNumberFormatter`, but I'm looking for a more direct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for everything you need to know about format specifiers.

You want:

```
int dig = 4; // for example
NSString *formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", dig, myFloat];
```

`dig` is used where the `*` is to indicate the number of digits after the decimal point.