# Float NSString Conversation Issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am working on a application in which I am generating some Tickets using  calculations.
For Generating Tickets I have created a model class and Inserting values into appropriate object.
Now I am having a Object

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) float crv;
```

I am adding a value into this from my textfiled like this :

```
ticketitem.crv = [txtCRV.text floatValue];
```

ticketitem is my Model class object.
Now my

> txtCRV.text is 1.58 but  ticketitem.crv becomes 1.58000004

I have tried all possible ways like rounded, Converting into string and then float and so on. but nothing seems to be working 
I want  ticketitem.crv == 1.58 only as it as my textfield value.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please have a look at [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a float only show two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
float rounded = roundf([txtCRV.text floatValue] * 100) / 100.0;
```

Let me know if you face problem using it.

Comment: It gives the same 1.58000004

Comment: can you post the output of this: NSLog(roundf([txtCRV.text floatValue] * 100) / 100.0); i am using same but i use only roundf(value) as i don't need decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ur code with this line

```
ticketitem.crv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.2f", txtCRV.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

%f = 25.000000

%.f = 25

%.02f = 25.00

```
ticketitem.crv = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [txtCRV.text floatValue]]floatValue];
```